# Rolling in POAOperations errors

Tags: tomcat

new guy here...keep rolling in the following errors about every 5 minutes on an apache/tomcat solaris machine. I can compare to another working machine and noticed a bunch of corba stuff missing. Placed all those directories in place....but no change. Can anybody give me the basics of what they see here? The output below is from the tomcat log. Apache log looks good.

StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/PortableServer/POAOperations

```
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:64)

    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:133)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:311)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:301)

    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:248)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:284)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:204)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:257)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:245)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:199)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:195)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:164)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:149)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:156)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardValveContext.invokeNext(StandardValveContext.java:151)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:564)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:972)

    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:206)

    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:324)

    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:395)

    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:673)

    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:615)

    at org.apache.jk.common.SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:786)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:479)
```

Comment: Most likely you are either missing the jar that is needed or missing the correct version of the jar. You are missing Corba jars.

Comment: Super..., thanks! compared and found an *.jar file that was indeed missing.